# "Make sure he's never found" grammar

Tags: grammar

This phrase is from Aladdin cartoon. I can't understand grammatical structure of this sentence - tense, voice, he's = he is or he has?

Comment: It's an imperative clause, and imperatives use the plain (infinitival) form of the verb and hence are tenseless. The embedded subordinate clause "he's never found", though, is present tense, passive voice. ("He's = "he is")

Answer (score 1):

The usage is

> Make sure he **is** never found.

The incomplete sentence

> Make sure he **has** never found

would require an object, such as

> Make sure he has never found gold.

but that sentence doesn't make sense, unless it is about tampering with historical records.

Comment: Weather Vane, thank you. But here we talk about future - "Make sure he is never found (in future)"? I thought that it is more appropriately to say "Make sure he will never be found"?

Comment: Present tense can be used to refer to any time frame, in the right context; see [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally?](/q/21846/26083) Further, “never” means “not at any time”, so “I never eat green eggs” means, roughly, “I have never eaten green eggs, I am not currently eating green eggs, and I will not ever eat green eggs in the future.”  It’s perfectly normal to use present tense in a command that refers to the future, e.g., “Never eat moldy bread.”  In fact, I’m not sure how I could say that in the future tense, absent a passive clause (“Make sure the bread is never eaten”).

Comment: Scott, good explanation about "never". But why not use passive voice future: "Make sure the bread will never be eaten", "You will never be forgotten" etc? Is this correct to say: "You are never forgotten?" and is it equivalent to "You will never be forgotten"?